# Getting Unexexpted token caused error due to loader when using Stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to integrate Stripe checkout into a VueJS application, but get the following error when the app compiles;

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (152:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         opts.auth = args.pop();
|       } else if (utils.isOptionsHash(arg)) {
|         const params = {...args.pop()};
| 
|         const extraKeys = Object.keys(params).filter(
 @ ./node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js 44:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/app/CMS/eCommerce/Checkout.vue
 @ ./src/app/CMS/eCommerce/Checkout.vue
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8082 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I happens when i add the following variable to mt Checkout.vue file;

import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = Stripe('MYAPI');

Here is we webpack file

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
          outputPath: 'assets/images/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Any advice would be great. Thank you

Comment: first, what versoin of node.js are you running? .... there's some ting wrong in `./node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js` at line 152 maybe? perhaps your version of node.js doesn't understand `...` (in this case, *rest* in objects)

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX thanks for your feedback, i am running Node v14.11.0 and cant figure out what loader is missing to read the rest in objects in my vue app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like something went wrong in the file `./src/app/CMS/eCommerce/Checkout.vue`.

First: Do both variables **arg** and **args** really exist?

Second: In order for the syntax `params = {...args.pop()}` to work `args`muss be an array of objects

Third: Do you have a babel config file? Because I think you need the babel preset "@babel/preset-env" or some babel plugins like "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" and "@babel/plugin-transform-spread" for babel to transpile the code for the browser...

A minimal babel.config.js can look like this:

```
module.exports = api => {
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = [];
    const plugins = [];

    /*
    // If you want to transpile just some syntaxes manually - micromanagement
    plugins.push(
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-spread" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals" ],
        [ "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions", { spec: false } ],
    );
    */
    
    // Or let babel transpile everthing
    presets.push(
        [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
    )

    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @kossi thanks for your comments and feedback, i appreciate it. The `params = {...args.pop()}` is coming from the utils/stripe fnc when i import stripe into the checkout.vue file. Also i am using webpack, I have tried to add the `'@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'` to it with no change to the error message.

Comment: Oh okay - so the utils/stripe function is under node_modules. But you configure webpack to ignore everything under node_modules ```exclude: /node_modules/```, so they will not be transpiled... Try ```/node_modules\/(?!(stripe)\/).*/```  to let webpack ignore everything under node_modules but the stripe package... I hope it dose the trick @WhileyMai